# Using Chrome Console with Firebase

Tags: javascript, console, firebase

As a js newbie, this is probably a dumb question. But how can I actually use js within a Chrome console. I am trying to interact with my Firebase via the console but when I try to get the Firebase reference I keep getting `undefined`. I know I can use Vulcan to visualize my data within the console but how can I actually execute basic javascript?

For example, I just want to get a reference to my Firebase and read data, like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");
// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

How can I type these commands in the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code will already work if you run it in the Chrome developer tools when you're in the Firebase Dashboard. The `Firebase` object is already available there.

In other tabs, the availability depends on how the page includes Firebase. If it includes it globally, you can execute your code. If the page does not expose `Firebase`, I normally inject it into the page with a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js'; document.head.appendChild(script);
```

So you add a bookmark to your Bookmarks Bar (mine is called `FB`) and set the URL to be the above JavaScript snippet. Then when you click the FB link, it will inject the Firebase script into the current page.

After that I normally start with a script that I've tied to a keyboard shortcuts:

```
new Firebase('https://mine.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) { console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val())); }, console.error)
```

Then I just replace `mine` with the actual name of the Firebase and I'm in a good place to get started.

Comment: This is great- thank you SO much @FrankVanPuffelen ! I know that was a very generic, beginner Javascript question but I'm trying to learn js and Firebase so this really helps. Thanks you!

Comment: We're all beginners when we just get started. Keep at it, and you'll outgrow that feeling in no time.... no, scrap that: I'm still a beginner, just a senior one. :-)